# Am unable to increase Height of Codemirror React Component

Tags: reactjs, codemirror

In my React application, I am using 'Editor.jsx component (which is just a wrapper around code-mirror, in case I need to provide frills around the actual CodeMirror-view).

The  in which the rendered component from attached file is added to, has height of 100% and other components similar to CodeMirror do use that full height.

The CodeMirror component however only shows 15 lines (and i have to scroll to get to the ones below).

The code is very similar to the sample from github.   The `height` property in getInitialState() also has no effect (neither does the containing ).

```
import React from 'react';
var CodeMirror = require('react-codemirror');

// fishing this 'require' out has caused severe headache and cost time.
// IF not included, default bootstrap style used. must override it with this.
// but for react-codemirror component we need this one!!!
// REF http://dorianpula.ca/2015/10/07/adding-a-code-editor-to-rookeries/
require("codemirror/lib/codemirror.css");
require('codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript');
require('codemirror/mode/python/python');

var DFLTS = {
  javascript: 'var component = {\n\tname: "react-codemirror",\n\tauthor: "Jed Watson",\n\tforUseBy: "KB"}',
  python: 'print "hello python world"'
}

export default React.createClass ({

  localOnCodeChange(newCode) {
    this.props.onCodeChange(newCode)
  },
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      code: DFLTS.javascript,
      readOnly: false,
      mode: 'javascript',
      height:"100%",
      viewportMargin: "Infinity"

    };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    CodeMirror.setSize("100%", 1000);
  },

  changeMode(e) {
    // add python later.
    // no-op
  },

  toggleRreadOnly() {
    this.setState({
      readOnly: !this.state.readOnly
    }, () => this.refs.editor.focus());
  },

  interact(cm) {
    console.log(cm.getValue());
  },

  render() {
    var options = {
      lineNumbers: true,
      readOnly: this.state.readOnly,
      mode: this.state.mode
    };

    return (
          <CodeMirror ref="editor" value={this.props.code} onChange={this.props.onCodeChange} options={options} interact={this.interact}/>
    )
  }
});
```

Any pointers, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.CodeMirror` class in this library appears to have a hard-coded `height: 300px` in it and there's an unanswered question in their issues about being able to set the height. If you put `.CodeMirror { min-height: 100% }` in your CSS that might do the trick.

Alternatively pass a `className` to `<CodeMirror>` (it will get added to the classes) that sets a min height, or a height with `!important`, or just greater specificity.

(Tsk tsk to components that you have to fight with :))

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!    .CodeMirror { height:100% !important} worked.  adding inline style={xxx} didn't, btw.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to dynamically change the height, or simply dont want to use css you can use `ref`

```
const codemirrorRef = React.useRef();

React.useEffect(() => {
  const current = codemirrorRef.current.editor.display.wrapper.style.height = "1000px";
});

<CodeMirror
    [...]           
    ref={codemirrorRef}
/>
```

`codemirrorRef.current.editor.display.wrapper` contains the div element. From there you can do anything you would do if you did `document.getElementById('#id')`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the height to override by adding an addition to the existing CodeMirror class in my CSS file as follows:

```
.CodeMirror {
  height: 100% !important
}
```

it only applied the change after adding `!important` to force it to override the existing class which is hard coded to 300 pixels.